# How to display search results from two tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to send a query to view
my result which is acquired from two tables.

```
var ticketPrice = from _ticketPrice in db.tbl_Concert_Hall_Floor_Place_TicketPrice
                          join _showtime in db.tbl_Concert_Showtime on _ticketPrice.ShowtimeID equals _showtime.ShowtimeID
                          join _concertHall in db.tbl_Concert_ConcertHall on _showtime.ConcertHallID equals _concertHall.ConcertHallID
                          join _concert in db.tbl_Content_Context on _concertHall.ContextID equals _concert.ContextID
                          where _concert.EnContextID == concertid
                          select new
                          {
                              _ticketPrice,
                              Showtime = _showtime.StartDate + " - ساعت " + _showtime.StartTime.ToString().Substring(0, 5) + "  الی    " + _showtime.EndTime.ToString().Substring(0, 5)

                          };
```

How to show the query in view?

Comment: no body can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend against using dynamics. The correct way to do this is to create a viewmodel.

```
public class TicketPriceViewModel
{
    public decimal  TicketPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can select with your viewmodel:

```
var ticketPrice = from _ticketPrice in db.tbl_Concert_Hall_Floor_Place_TicketPrice
    join _showtime in db.tbl_Concert_Showtime on _ticketPrice.ShowtimeID equals _showtime.ShowtimeID
    join _concertHall in db.tbl_Concert_ConcertHall on _showtime.ConcertHallID equals _concertHall.ConcertHallID
    join _concert in db.tbl_Content_Context on _concertHall.ContextID equals _concert.ContextID
    where _concert.EnContextID == concertid
    select new TicketPriceViewModel
    {
        TicketPrice = _ticketPrice,
        StartDate = _showtime.StartDate,
        StartTime = _showtime.StartTime,
        EndTime = _showtime.EndTime
    };
```

Pass the viewmodel to your view:

```
return View(ticketPrice);
```

Use that model in your view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TicketPriceViewModel>

// Example
@foreach (var ticket in Model)
{
    <span>Starting time: @ticket.StartDate - ساعت @ticket.StartTime.ToString().Substring(0, 5)  الی   @ticket.EndTime.ToString().Substring(0, 5)</span>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember I was trapped in this situation before. I solved it by using dynamic model in the view.

Try to declare your model in the view as dynamic as below:

```
@model dynamic
```

And then you can access your data field of the anonymous type. Hope this can help.